# Manipulate Excel files

Tags: c#, .net, excel

How can I add to the Author property of an Excel document automatically? I want to use c# 4 for this.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137763/accessing-excel-custom-document-properties-programatically

Comment: do i need to install ms office on the machine for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Document Properties This link explains how to read the document properties and gives a list of properties which you can access.

```
private void DisplayBuiltinDocumentProperties()
```

{
    Office.DocumentProperties documentProperties1 =
        (Office.DocumentProperties)this.BuiltinDocumentProperties;

```
if (documentProperties1 != null)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= documentProperties1.Count; i++)
    {
        Office.DocumentProperty dp = documentProperties1[i];
        Globals.Sheet1.Range["A" + i.ToString(), missing].Value2 =
            dp.Name;
    }
}
```

}

Here's a list of imports required :

using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Microsoft.Office.Core;   // (Com Object, Office 12 object library)`

Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties a = (Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties)workbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties;
            a[2].Value = "new Author";

Hope that helps

Comment: can I just copy the binary without installing Office to the machine?

Answer (score 0):

As you specified C# 4, you can use the following:

```
Workbook wbk = app.Workbooks.Add();

dynamic properties = wbk.BuiltinDocumentProperties;
dynamic property = properties.Item("Author");

property.Value = "J K Rowling";
```